# Global on mutable vs immutable

Tags: python, global

Is the following a correct understanding of `global` on mutable vs immutable objects?

```
immutable1 = 'abc'
immutable2 = '123'
mutable = {}

def change():    
    mutable['CHANGED'] = 'CHANGED' # this will change the global variable mutable
    global immutable1
    immutable1 = 'abc-CHANGED' # this will change the global variable immutable1 because global has been called
    immutable2 = '123-CHANGED' # this will not change the global immutable2 variable, because it's immutable and global has not bee declared
```

Is the only usage of `global` to modify a global immutable variable, or can it ever be used in other situations?

Another example:

```
>>> m={}
>>> i='a'
>>> 
>>> def change():
...     m['a'] = i
...     i = 'b'
... 
>>> print(m,i)
{} a
>>> change()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`global` has nothing to do with mutability. It changes the *scope* of a *name*, whether the global refers to a mutable or immutable object, so that you can assign a different value to the name.

When assigning to a global name, the old value may or may not have been mutable, and the new value can be either as well.

```
d = {}
e = 6

def change():
    global d, e
    d = 3
    e = []
```

Comment: how am I able to change the mutable dict then but not the immutable string without calling `global` on the string?

Comment: You have to distinguish between changing what a name refers to and modifying the object already referred to by the name. `mutable['CHANGED'] = 'CHANGED'` does not change what `mutable` is bound to; it modifies the existing object. Technically, it's not an assignment; it's special syntax for a method call `mutable.__setitem__('CHANGED', 'CHANGED')`.